# Ternary Operator condition in JQuery Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have stored the HTML inside a variable and I am appending it on a specific condition. I wanted to add an `active` class by using a ternary condition. I have given the condition inside the function, but the class is not getting added in the div.

Can someone please explain how to use a ternary condition in the `div`?

```js
function reusableGenerateFacilities(facilityListArray, contentHtml, listHeader, divFacilityAppend) {
  $.each(facilityListArray, function(key) {
    contentHtml = contentHtml + "<div class='contentbox locationSelected'><p class='locationtext'>" + facilityListArray[key].LocationName + "</p><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='editLocationName pull-right'>Edit</a><div class='editLocationPanel'><input type='text' class='locationTextBox' /><div class='editFacilityBtn'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='cancelEdit'>Cancel</a><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-primary saveLocationName pull-right'>Save</a></div></div></div>";

    if (key == facilityListArray.length - 1) {
      $("." + divFacilityAppend).append("<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 mainWrapper'><div class='listHeader'><p class='" + listHeader + "'>" + facilityListArray[key].LevelName + "</p><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='editLevelName pull-right'>Edit All</a><div class='editLocationPanel'><input type='text' class='LevelNameTextBox' /><div class='editFacilityBtn'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='cancelEdit'>Cancel</a><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-primary saveAllLevelNames pull-right'>Save</a></div></div></div><div class='location-wrapper'>" + contentHtml + "</div><div class='addLocation'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-default addLocationBtn' data-levelid=" + facilityListArray[key].Level + ">+ " + facilityListArray[key].LevelName + "</a></div></div>");
    }

    (key == 0) ? $(".contentbox").addClass('active') : $(".contentbox").removeClass('active');
    debugger
  });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: when you use $(".contentbox").addClass('active') the selector ".content" should be a DOM element make sure you append your code to DOM to which you want to toggle active class before terinary operation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to toggle class for content HTML which you are appending in the function
Try something like this code

```
function reusableGenerateFacilities(facilityListArray, contentHtml, listHeader, divFacilityAppend) {
  $.each(facilityListArray, function(key) {
    contentHtml = contentHtml + "<div class='contentbox locationSelected "+((key == 0) ? 'active' : '')+"'><p class='locationtext'>" + facilityListArray[key].LocationName + "</p><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='editLocationName pull-right'>Edit</a><div class='editLocationPanel'><input type='text' class='locationTextBox' /><div class='editFacilityBtn'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='cancelEdit'>Cancel</a><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-primary saveLocationName pull-right'>Save</a></div></div></div>";

    if (key == facilityListArray.length - 1) {
      $("." + divFacilityAppend).append("<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 mainWrapper'><div class='listHeader'><p class='" + listHeader + "'>" + facilityListArray[key].LevelName + "</p><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='editLevelName pull-right'>Edit All</a><div class='editLocationPanel'><input type='text' class='LevelNameTextBox' /><div class='editFacilityBtn'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='cancelEdit'>Cancel</a><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-primary saveAllLevelNames pull-right'>Save</a></div></div></div><div class='location-wrapper'>" + contentHtml + "</div><div class='addLocation'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-default addLocationBtn' data-levelid=" + facilityListArray[key].Level + ">+ " + facilityListArray[key].LevelName + "</a></div></div>");
    }

    (key == 0) ? $(".contentbox").addClass('active') : $(".contentbox").removeClass('active');
    debugger
  });
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you changed here?

Comment: i have added conditional statement in content html variable itself in fist line of each callback function

Comment: Ah okay! Great.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the following...

```
(key == 0) ? $(".contentbox").addClass('active') : $(".contentbox").removeClass('active');
```

You should really do [`.toggleClass( className, state )`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state):

```
$(".contentbox").toggleClass("active", key == 0);
```

You can also add a custom function as the second parameter instead of a ternary expression.

Answer (score -2):

you can add class in div as below :

```
var addClass;
    addClass = (key == 0) ? 'active': '';
    contentHtml = contentHtml + "<div class='contentbox locationSelected "+addClass+"'><p class='locationtext'>" + facilityListArray[key].LocationName + "</p><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='editLocationName pull-right'>Edit</a><div class='editLocationPanel'><input type='text' class='locationTextBox' /><div class='editFacilityBtn'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='cancelEdit'>Cancel</a><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-primary saveLocationName pull-right'>Save</a></div></div></div>";
```